# Анонимная рекурсивная функция

Tags: javascript

Если есть анонимная функция

```
(function(value){
    // Вызываем сами себя
})();
```

как из нее вызвать саму себя (с целью получения рекурсии)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(function(value){
    arguments.callee(value);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Приходилось сталкиваться с рекурсией анонимной функции.
Поддерживаю ответ Дмитрия, но советую использовать:

```js
(callee = function(){
   callee();
})();
```

Так как часто в рекурсивной функции есть много callback-ов в которых `arguments.callee(value);` будет вызывать эти же callback-и.